# Spring3 pooling vs WebSphere's pooling?

Tags: spring, websphere, spring-3, pool

I have a J2EE web application which uses Spring3 framework and will eventually be deployed on WebSphere Application Server 8.5. We wanted to implement some pooling for our web application. However, both Spring3 and WebSphere Application Server has support for pooling.

Should we use the pooling provided by Spring3 or should we use the one provided by WebSphere? Which is more efficient to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Pooling of what? (http connections, db connection, beans, ...)

Comment: @Ralph: Custom objects. It's under `Resources > Object pool managers`. But I don't know how to set its properties. Do you know how to set it? Thanks!

Comment: could you please explain how you want to pool "Custom objects" with Spring -- because is still do not understand what you exactly want to pool.

Comment: @Ralph: For Spring 3, I use the AOP api. I followed the instruction here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop-api.html . It's under `8.10.2 Pooling target sources`.

Comment: this is not what I ment: do you want to implement something like a method result cache, or do you want to resuse some objects because they are expensive to create, or what/how do you want to pool.